# ESP32 doesn't connect to Arduino. | could not open port 'COM2': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

### ERROR:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM2': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

**I've tried literally everything.**

- Drives checks out! | Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge (installed!)
- Restarting the computer didn't make any difference
- Restarting apps and stuff
- Arduino's Serial monitor is closed
- The cable is ok! Brand new and testing with other cables (also tested) don't work
- The led in the ESP is on and stable, I could upload the sketch wifi scan code once, it keeps looping and just works properly, but I cannot upload new data and/or update the code within the esp32
- I've tried holding the buttons in every way possible, it doesn't make any difference.

++
[image: device manager :: connected ports]

help :(

Comment: Nothing else has the port open? It’s the correct port? Can you connect to it with a different machine?

Comment: Check whether the board appears as ```USB to serial CP210x``` or some variant of it on device manager. If it does  appear you can rule out a hardware issue.

Comment: if the port appears in the device manager when you plug the board in, then the hardware is working between windows and the UART bridge ... the `access denied` is a windows message that is probably not related to the UART bridge

Comment: @DaveNewton no I haven't tried connecting it to another machine.

Comment: @Coder9390 I'll update the question with the device manager's ports image